# Filtering a CSV file to find if a the country is present in a defined list

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to pull data out of a spreadsheet and create new csv's for each country and continent.

The country section works well as the countries are already present in the spreadsheet.

However when i try to create a new csv file for each continent i reference a text file with a list of all the countries in said continent.

I am struggling to get the for loop to check whether the country is in a continent. The csv files generate for each continent however they are empty and not written to.

```
'''
pull data from spreadsheet
'''



import pandas as pd

# Create data
df = pd.read_csv('Copy of KEYWORD LIST_ALL.csv')


# Set index
df = df.set_index('Keyword')

#get list of destinations
destlist = df['Destination'].tolist()

#turn list into set to make it easier to work with
destinations = set(destlist)


continents = ['Asia','Europe','Africa','North America','South America','Oceania']

#loop to create a csv for each destination
for dest in destinations:
    tempdf = df[(df['Destination'] == dest)]
    tempdf.to_csv(dest + ".csv")
    print(tempdf.head())
    #print(dest)
```

This is the loop I have issues with, I can open the file but in the line

```
tempdf = df[(df['Destination'] in countries)]
```

I cannot compare the equality as I have to use a bitwise operator? even though i want to use the 'in' equality check

```
for cont in continents:
    with open("C:/Users/HarryAdams/PycharmProjects/untitled/" + cont + ".txt") as fileobj:
        countries = fileobj.readlines()
        tempdf = df[(df['Destination']  countries)]
        tempdf.to_csv(cont + ".csv")
        print(tempdf.head())
```

Sample row of csv:

```
Keyword,MSV,Rank,Value,Landing Page,Meta,Page,Destination,Destination 2


luxury holidays antigua, 40 , 1 , 8 ,http://www.kuoni.co.uk/antigua/luxury-antigua-holidays,Luxury Antigua Holidays - Kuoni,"Award winning, ATOL protected Antigua luxury holidays. Great range of Antigua all inclusive resorts. Book with Kuoni, receive all inclusive value.",Antigua,Antigua
```

Comment: I gave you -1 for not isolating your problem and sharing sample data.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a sample of your CSV data. Or a link to it.

Comment: Apologies, the data is 80,000 rows long so I didnt include it, added a sample now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't test this but it might be worth a try.
Why don't you read in the countries via pandas as well?
And I guess in this case you should use `.isin` since you are comparing to series.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create data
df = pd.read_csv('Copy of KEYWORD LIST_ALL.csv')


# Set index
df = df.set_index('Keyword')

for dest, group in df.groupby('destination'):
    group.to_csv(dest + '.csv')

continents = ['Asia','Europe','Africa','North America','South America','Oceania']

directory = "C:/Users/HarryAdams/PycharmProjects/untitled/"

for cont in continents:
    countries = pd.read_table(directory + cont + '.txt')
    df[df.destination.isin(countries[countries.columns[0]])].to_csv(cont + '.csv')
```